# How can I get opionset value on RetrieveMultiple

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I'm doing RetrieveMultiple call with following query:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="lt_myentity">
    <attribute name="lt_id" />
    <attribute name="lt_changetype" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It's working fine but lt_changetype is defined as optionset so in result I'm getting IDs like 206420010. How can I get values instead?

I know about RetrieveAttributeRequest but maybe it's possible to do this without second call and matching.

Comment: The number *is* the value of the attribute. Labels have nothing to do with the data, are managed via translations and are stored elsewhere (although non-global optionsets should be included in the `FormattedValues` member of the `Entity` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF You Want to Get the **OptionSetValue** You Can use **FormattedValues** Property After Getting the Data from FetchXML. Kindly Check this [FormattedValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.formattedvalues.aspx)